# Restore HP Envy dv6 to factory settings

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, hp

I bought a HP Envy dv6 and tried to dual boot with Ubuntu 13.04. Since I couldn't get it to work, I figured out that I could do it with Windows 7. The thing is that the wifi drivers aren't available, so that meant that I couldn't install any other driver.

After that I installed Ubuntu over Windows 7 and I think that just deleted all the factory partitions. Now I want to make a system recovery to a factory restore but I can't.

This is very complicated for me, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In some laptops, by default you cannot go to restore menu. for this you need to find its option and enable it in bios setup